# Skip parent id from mysql join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query which is working perfect.

```
$stmt = "select t.tax_name, "
        . "(select truncate( sum((i.item_tax / 100) * i.item_qty_total), 2 ) from {CI}invoice_items i "
        . "where i.tax_id = t.tax_id $qs ) total_tax, "
        . "(select truncate( sum(i.item_qty_total), 2 ) from {CI}invoice_items i "
        . "where i.tax_id = t.tax_id $qs ) turnover "
        . "from {CI}taxes t ";
```

### Output

[image: First output]

But the problem is i have to skip the invoice_items according to invoice status, i tried it like this

```
$stmt = "select t.tax_name, "
      . "(select truncate( sum((i.item_tax / 100) * i.item_qty_total), 2 ) from {CI}invoice_items i "
      . "left join {CI}invoices inv on inv.invoice_id = i.invoice_id and inv.status not like 'cancel%' "
      . "where i.tax_id = t.tax_id $qs ) total_tax, "
      . "(select truncate( sum(i.item_qty_total), 2 ) from {CI}invoice_items i "
      . "left join {CI}invoices inv on inv.invoice_id = i.invoice_id and inv.status not like 'cancel%' "
      . "where i.tax_id = t.tax_id $qs ) turnover "
      . "from {CI}taxes t ";
```

But the join not affect on the result, its display same result that first query provide. What is the problem in my JOIN?

### Expected Result:

[image]

[image]

Here is the schema of `invoice_items`

```
 CREATE TABLE `ci_invoice_items` (
   `ii_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'INVOICE_ITEM_ID',
   `invoice_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `customer_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `item_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `invoice_date` datetime NOT NULL,
   `item_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   `item_unit` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `item_qty` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
   `item_qty_total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'TOTAL_AMOUNT_INCLUDING_QUANTITY',
   `item_tax` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   `item_tax_total` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'TOTAL_AMOUNT_INCLUDING_TAX',
   `tax_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
   `item_description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ii_id`),
 KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`,`customer_id`,`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=170 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and `invoices`

```
 CREATE TABLE `ci_invoices` (
   `invoice_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `customer_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
   `tmp_inv_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
   `inv_prefix` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `invoice_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `invoice_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `order_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
   `inter_state` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `form` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `order_date` datetime NOT NULL,
   `ref_number` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   `com_ref_per` varchar(150) NOT NULL COMMENT 'COMPANY_REFF_NUMBER',
   `com_ref_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'COMPANY_REFF_NAME',
   `due_date` datetime NOT NULL,
   `invoice_date` datetime NOT NULL,
   `invoice_note` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `shipping_address` text NOT NULL,
   `tax_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
   `shipping` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
   `total_amount` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
   `round_off_amt` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ROUND_OFF_AMOUNT',
   `paid_amount` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
   `c_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'CURRENT_DATE',
   `made_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unpaid',
   `reset_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`),
 KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you show the behaviour you are looking for using example data?  Showing the raw inputs, the desired outputs, and describing what was and was not done to achieve those outputs.  *(Also, what is in `$qs`?)*

Comment: @MatBailie let me edit my post

Comment: @MatBailie i have edited my question, and the `$qs` is the query params that i am handler to use filter. But now it is `$qs = ""`

Comment: place `not like 'cancel%'` in `where` clause rather than join clause and check!

Comment: @jogesh_pi - You're doing a `LEFT JOIN` on to the invoices.  Could you explain why this isn't an `INNER JOIN`?  If it does need to be a `LEFT JOIN`, how do you want to treat a case where there is no invoice record?  Will that count as ***cancelled*** or ***not-cancelled***?

Comment: @MatBailie now its working, NoobEditor solution was working for me, thanks to both of you :)

Comment: @jogesh_pi - Just note that, by moving the condition to a `WHERE` clause, you ***have*** effectively turned the `LEFT JOIN` in to an `INNER JOIN`.  Any records that don't have a matching invoice ***will not*** be included in these results.